# Unable to create PeerAdminCard following Hyperledger Composer tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I could not proceed further at `composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network`.

[Link to tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html)

I then ran `createPeerAdminCard.sh` in the fabric-tools folder under my blockchain code main folder. The process finished but no card was created.

```
(anaconda2) $ ./createPeerAdminCard.sh 
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv1
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Need to have composer-cli installed at v0.15 or greater
```

This seems to suggest a problem. The expected output should be something like the below, based on a reference I found [here from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html):

```
Successfully created business network card to /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card

Command succeeded

Successfully imported business network card: PeerAdmin@hlfv1

Command succeeded

Hyperledger Composer PeerAdmin card has been imported
The following Business Network Cards are available:


┌─────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ CardName        │ UserId    │ Network │
├─────────────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ PeerAdmin@hlfv1 │ PeerAdmin │         │
└─────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┘

Issue composer card list --name <CardName>  to get details of the card

Command succeeded
```

Then I managed to run `npm install -g composer-cli` to attempt to update *composer-cli* to 0.16.2 after a lot of fiddling to point `npm config` to python 2.7 as my main python is python 3 set up through anaconda.

```
....
gyp info ok 

> grpc@1.6.6 install /Users/userdirectory/Hyperledger/my-business-network/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

[grpc] Success: "/Users/userdirectory/Hyperledger/my-business-network/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> protobufjs@6.6.3 postinstall /Users/userdirectory/Hyperledger/my-business-network/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN my-business-network@0.0.1 No repository field.

+ composer-cli@0.16.2
added 1055 packages in 48.356s
```

This appears to suggest composer-cli was updated. But I still ran into the same log output when I run `createPeerAdminCard.sh`.

I could not find a way to check the version of my *composer-cli*. Without the card, it also means I could not proceed further to install composer runtime. Any help is much appreciated.

> Please note I am not following the tutorial from installation to this
>   point because I have had coded up a simple *business network*,
>   exported the *bna* file, deployed it and played with it on the
>   playground in the browser some time back in August. I'd like to
>   further the experiment by generating a REST server for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake when I attempted to update `composer-cli`. I should have run `npm install -g composer-cli` instead of incorrectly running `npm install composer-cli`. The latter command somehow did not update `composer-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I've found this github ticket: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2714

Basically you cannot use node version 6, but you also CANNOT use the latest version 9. I did a clean uninstall and install using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dotcomputercraft/b7283bd52f4b5389e748). Then in install node again and nvm.  Then I make sure to install **v8.9.1**, yes not v8.10.1 like the tutorial.

```
nvm install v8.9.1  
nvm use 8.9.1  # telling nvm to use npm 8.9.1
npm install -g  composer-cli  --unsafe-perm
```

Other other related composer package should be appended as **npm install -g [package-name] --unsafe-perm**

That does the trick for me, then I was able to run
    ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
    composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName anh-tutorial-network

The **anh-tutorial-network** is what I call my business network, however the --businessNetworkName must stay the same for this example.

Error Log

> ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
>       Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
>       Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
>       FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv1
>       FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

```
Need to have composer-cli installed at version 0.16

akhs-MacBook-Pro:fabric-tools akh$ npm install -g composer-cli --save
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/npm-shrinkwrap.json
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno -62
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/npm-shrinkwrap.json'
```